# adding a new column **attachment** in existing table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok So I have a simple rails application called ticket. here I create ticket and store into database. I generated it using scaffold.

```
It has 5 columns. ( I generated it using scaffold)
 Name
 Seat id seq
 Address
 Price paid
 Email Address
```

And the application is working fine. I can create , edit, and update the ticket. I am much interested in creating the ticket rather than editing and deleting.

Now I want to add a new column in the database named *attachment* where a person can upload word, pdf files. I have seen many tutorials but none is explaining how I can incorporate into an existing table which already have some fields.

**tickets_controller.rb**

```
  class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ticket }
  else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ticket }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @ticket.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tickets_url, notice: 'Ticket was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_ticket
      @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    end


    def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :seat_id_seq, :address, :price_paid, :email_address)
    end
end
```

**tickets Model**

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(ticket) do |f| %>
  <% if ticket.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(ticket.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this    ticket from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :seat_id_seq %>
  <%= f.text_field :seat_id_seq %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_area :address %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price_paid %>
  <%= f.text_field :price_paid %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email_address %>
  <%= f.text_field :email_address %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Ticket</h1>

<%= render 'form', ticket: @ticket %>

<%= link_to 'Back', tickets_path %>
```

I found some on some of the sources that to upload a document we need to create a table with three columns ( filename, content_type, data) , and I thought to add these column into the existing tickets table, but then I don't know what chnages i need to make in the new.html.erb file. On this file i am loading the form where you can enter the information, and I want to show a field to upload a file on this page.

ruby -v : 2.2.6p396
rails -v : 5.0.0.1 ( Please reply in way that I can use the solution on the rails 4.0 too)

Comment: depends. Simple way is to create a migration to add column for your file to your table and then install CarrierWave for uploading files - are you aware of these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brad mentioned you can use paperclip or carrierwave to add attachment. I will use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) in this example. ( ***Note:*** I'm using rails 5.0.0.1 in this example, and comand `rails db:migrate`. in Rails 4.x it will be `rake db:migrate`)

Let's do some scaffolding first and then you can alter your code to suits your needs.

```
rails g scaffold User name:string
rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text user:references
```

Add `has_many :posts` to User model, and run  `rails db:migrate`

Add gem file: `gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"` and run: `bundle install`

Let's generate paperclip attachment: `rails generate paperclip user docs` and run `rails db:migrate`

Add attachment, validation and content type to our User model:

```
  has_attached_file :docs
  validates_attachment :docs, :content_type => {:content_type => %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
```

Add to **users_controller.rb** strong params for attribute whitelisting :

```
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :docs)
  end
```

The form’s encoding must be set to **multipart/form-data** for uploading files `html: { multipart: true }` so for our attachment we need to alter our form partial **app/views/users/_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

And add required fields to our form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :docs %>
    <%= f.file_field :docs %>
  </div>
```

After restarting our server `rails s`, and going to url **users/new** we can see new field attachment. After uploading a document we can check in our console if it's uploaded: `rails c` and run for example `User.all`, which shows that our fields in DB are populated:

[image]

And the last step would be to show the document in our views **app/views/users/show.html.erb** so that users can download or open it in the browser:

```
<%= link_to "My document", @user.docs.url, target: "_blank" %>
```

**EDIT**

---

Let's get back to your project and do it:

First you should add Paperclip gem to your Gemfile `gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"` and to run `bundle install` in command line.

Generate attachment: `rails generate paperclip ticket attachment` ( This will generate the migration file and add attachment field to it )

run `rails db:migrate` ( `rake db:migrate` in Rails 4 )
go to Ticket model and add:

```
has_attached_file :attachment
  validates_attachment :attachment, :content_type => {:content_type => %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
```

Then to **tickets_controller.rb** and edit strong params:

```
   def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :seat_id_seq, :address, :price_paid, :email_address, :attachment)
    end
```

Go to your partial **_form.html.erb**:

Edit this code below in your form:

```
<%= form_for @ticket, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Add this code below to your form: (That would be new field with attachment )

```
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :attachment %>
   <%= f.file_field :attachment %>  
  </div>
```

and the last step to your show page add:

```
  <%= link_to "My document", @ticket.attachment.url, target: "_blank" %>
```

restart your server, upload the document and try if it works.

Comment: rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text user:references  , what this line is actually doing.. Because I have a table tickets , do I need to create another table Post and add  title:string body:text user:references fields into that.

Comment: It is rails scaffolding. Quick way to generate app. It will generate Post MVC with title and body fields and reference it to the User model, by adding `t.references :user, foreign_key: true` to migration file. I answered you as an example(tutorial) to show you how it can be done. Don't put in your code, unless you want to play around. Do you have a repository of your project? I will edit my answer and try to help you

Comment: I updated my answer, so that you can try now in your project. Please let me know if it works for you?

Comment: getting this error: Attachment has contents that are not what they are reported to be

Comment: Have you installed imagemagick processor? (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor)

Answer (score 0):

For adding attachments you can use a gem like [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). I personally use paperclip but both are good.

To do it manually:

In your terminal cd to app folder and run:

`rails g migration AddAttachmentToTickets attachment:blob`

run rails 4 `rake db:migrate` or in rails 5 `rails db:migrate`

in your ticket form you can now add:

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :attachment %>
   <%= f.file_field :attachment %>  
</div>
```

and make sure you permit this in your ticketsController params. It should look something like this:

```
def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:ticket_number,:description, :attachement)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's showing me a file uploaded #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000cd454e8> , how can I download it from database and read it's content, or how can I download it by web page, Does the file got uploaded with its content ?

Comment: Read the last section of this blog post. http://over9000.org/rails/saving-ruby-on-rails-attachments-as-blobs

Comment: In all honesty though, I would recommend using one of the gems I mentioned above. Life is easier with Gems :)

Comment: I beg to differ. Apparently what I learned a long time ago, it is a bad design to store images/docs as blobs in a database. It is advisable to store them as a files on the server, and their path should be stored in DB as string datatype. when you upload them for example with Paperclip gem, on your localhost, your docs should be in the public folder, and their path should be stored in DB as string data type. You can use other gems to upload them to external storages. for example: `gem 'aws-sdk' `. Take a look how to retrieve them in the last line I posted in my answer to your question.

Comment: @Blackcoat77 You are not differing, you are agreeing. I did say i reccomend using a gem and specificaly mention paperclip

Comment: @Brad I agree that you recommend using Paperclip gem, but differ about BLOB data type you posted in your answer.